# Poker hand evaluation in python: why is naive faster than bit hash?

Tags: python, poker

I am trying to create a python-based poker program. For the evaluation of hand values, I expected bit-hash evaluation to be much faster than naive evaluation (sorting and testing different hand levels). Yet using two libraries, I've actually encountered the opposite.

Does anyone have any experience with deuces/treys (the python 3 fork of deuces). 
https://github.com/worldveil/deuces

It is a cactus-kev style hashing tool that brute forces 7-card hands by running 21 (7 choose 5) separate 5-card evaluations. It is currently taking ~80s to evaluate two hands against each other for all permutations of the remaining cards. That is 2 hands * 1,712,304 boards * 21 7-card hands each or 72MM hands to evaluate.

So I'm realizing speeds of 900,000 evaluations/s, which seems in line or better than expectations.

Yet oddly, when I use Kevin Tseng's holdem_calc (https://github.com/ktseng/holdem_calc), I get the results for the same comparison in <20s.

It uses a naive sorting and hand-testing method - in addition to storing cards as objects instead of simple ints packed with bytes-level data. It seems this should be much heavier.

The  code is below. I've profiled it to confirm that it is the evaluate function using 95% of the time.

Why is naive so much faster? It seems to go against everything I've read so far.

deuces/treys code (change import):

```py
from deuces import Card, Deck, Evaluator
import itertools
import time

start = time.time()

evaluator = Evaluator()
deck = Deck()
p1_hand = deck.draw(2)
p2_hand = deck.draw(2)
hands = [p1_hand, p2_hand]

print(Card.print_pretty_cards(p1_hand))
print(Card.print_pretty_cards(p2_hand))

boards = [i for i in itertools.combinations(deck.cards, 5)]

p1_wins = 0
p1_ties = 0
for b in boards:
    p1_score = evaluator.evaluate(p1_hand, list(b))
    p2_score = evaluator.evaluate(p2_hand, list(b))
    if p1_score < p2_score:
        p1_wins += 1
    elif p1_score == p2_score:
        p1_ties += 1

print(float(p1_wins / len(boards)))
print(time.time() - start)
```

holdem_calc code (can also be run as CLI):

```py
from holdem_calc import main
import sys
import time

sys.argv.extend(['As', '8d', 'Qc', '9c'])
sys.argv.extend(['--exact'])
start = time.time()
main()
print "\nTime elapsed(seconds): ", time.time() - start
```

Comment: Something a bit off-topic, you might not be interested, but I came across this video a while back which might interest you: https://youtu.be/ebeEIy-q_NE

Comment: Looks like `holdem_calc` avoids looking at all (7 choose 5) combinations for each player through optimizations in `preprocess_board` and `find_winner` functions.

Comment: Have you tried my cardlib at onejoker.org?

Comment: Yeah, @hilberts_drinking_problem, definitely some pre-processing/sorting/calcs going on; however, I had expected the overhead of the naive to be way to great to overcome through such simple algorithms. But I guess not...

Thanks for the link GertjanBrouwer. I'll definitely check it out. I'm watching/reading a lot of similar stuff lately.